# Java Serial Port, handle serialEvent effectively

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-port, rxtx

Using the RXTX library I've encountered that on a serialEvent (when data arrives) I don't know how to reference the already running main application.

The way of making it work that I've found is to close the serial port when the endOfMessageFlag arrives (so I don't get the "lock file already exists error" when I try to send more data afterwards) and make a new instance of the class that handles the message.

I don't like this "solution" as I'm afraid is not very efficient and if many messages arrive together I would probably even get a stackoverflow exception.

I'm using rxtx-2.2-pre2 on raspbian.

I have three classes, one with the main, one with protocol and one that handles the serial port (initialize, send, (receive)serialEvent ).

Main class snipet:

```
package app;
public class MainClass {

    private MyProtocol myProt = new MyProtocol();
    public boolean newCDevices = false;
    public int newDevices = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyAMA0"); 
        MainClass myMain = new MainClass();
        monitorS.findDevices();
    }

    public void messageReceived(byte[] message){
        myProt.processMessage(message);
        myProt.sendAcknowledge();
    }

    private void findDevices(){
        myProt.findNewDevices();
    }
}
```

Protocol class snipet:

```
package serialcomms;
public class MyProtocol {

    private static SerialComms messageSender = new SerialComms();

    // sends acknowledge onReceive.
    public void sendAcknowledge(){        
        byte[] messageBytes = composeMessage(acknowledge);
        if(messageSender.initialize()){
            messageSender.sendData(messageBytes);
            try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            messageSender.close();
        }
    }

    //sends broadcast message asking all unidentified devices to make contact.
    public void findNewDevices(){
        byte[] messageBytes = composeMessage(findDevicesMessage);
        if(messageSender.initialize()){
            messageSender.sendData(messageBytes);
            try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            messageSender.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the class that handles the serial port:
(based on this example btw: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/control-an-arduino-from-java/240163864 )

```
    package serialcomms;

    import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
    import gnu.io.SerialPort;
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.time.Clock;
    import java.util.Enumeration;

    public class SerialComms implements SerialPortEventListener {

        SerialPort serialPort = null;

        private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
  //      "/dev/tty.usbmodem", // Mac OS X
//        "/dev/usbdev", // Linux
        "/dev/ttyAMA0", // Raspberry
//        "/dev/tty", // Linux
//       "/dev/serial", // Linux
//        "COM3", // Windows
    };

    private String appName;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private OutputStream output;  
    private int tail = 0;

    int lengthArray = 50;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[lengthArray];

    private static final int TIME_OUT = 1000; // Port open timeout
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600; // Arduino serial port

    private static final int BYTE_START = 100;
    private static final int BYTE_END = 120;
    private final byte startOfMessage = (byte)BYTE_START;
    private final byte endOfMessage = (byte)BYTE_END;

    public SerialComms(){
        appName = getClass().getName();
    }

    public boolean initialize() {
        try {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
            Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

            // Enumerate system ports and try connecting to Arduino over each
            //
            System.out.println( "Trying:");
            while (portId == null && portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                // Iterate through your host computer's serial port IDs
                //
                CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                System.out.println( "   port" + currPortId.getName() );
                for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                    if ( currPortId.getName().equals(portName) 
                      || currPortId.getName().startsWith(portName)) {

                        // Try to connect to the Arduino on this port
                        //
                        // Open serial port
                        serialPort = (SerialPort)currPortId.open(appName, TIME_OUT);
                        portId = currPortId;
                        System.out.println( "Connected on port" + currPortId.getName() );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (portId == null || serialPort == null) {
                System.out.println("Oops... Could not connect to Arduino");
                return false;
            }

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            // Give the Arduino some time
            try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] data) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending data: '" + data +"'");
            // open the streams and send 
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            output.write( data );
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    //
    // This should be called when you stop using the port
    //
    public synchronized void close() {
        if ( serialPort != null ) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }


    //
    // Handle serial port event
    //
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        try {
            while (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){

                    byte singleData = (byte)serialPort.getInputStream().read();
                    if (singleData == startOfMessage){
                        for(int i = 0; i < tail ; i++){
                            buffer[i] = 0x00;
                        }
                        tail = 0;
                        buffer[tail] = singleData;
                        tail++;

                    } else if(singleData == endOfMessage && tail <= buffer.length){ 
                        buffer[tail] = singleData;  
                        tail++;
                        for(int i = 0; i< tail ; i++){
                            System.out.println(buffer[i]);
                        }
                        close();                                //This are the lines that got it to
                        MainClass newMain = new MainClass();    //work. However I think there must
                        newMain.messageReceived(buffer);        //be a better solution.
                    } else if(tail < buffer.length){  
                        buffer[tail] = singleData;  
                        tail++;  
                    }

                    break;           
               default:
                    break;

    }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Edited serialEvent method on SerialComms so it would receive all available data instead of having to be interrupted for each byte received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better and very simple solution to my problem which is to declare a static array of bytes on my main class and store the received message there.

I'll repost the modified parts of code:

```
public class MainClass{
private static MyProtocol myProt = new MyProtocol();
    public static byte[] message = new byte[50];
    public boolean newMessage = false;
    private boolean runApp = true;
    public int newColectors = 0;
    private static final int START_OF_MESAGE = 100;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyAMA0"); 
        MainClass myApp = new MainClass();

        while(myApp.runApp){
            if(myApp.checkMessageReceived()){
                myProt.processMessage(message);
                myProt.sendAcknowledge();
            }
            myApp.findNewCollectors();

            try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }
    }

    public boolean checkMessageReceived(){
        if(message[0]== (byte) START_OF_MESAGE){
            newMessage = true;
        }
        return newMessage;
    }
```

}

And adding on the serial port handler class:

```
MainClass.message = buffer;
```

instead of:

```
close();                                //This are the lines that got it to
MainClass newMain = new MainClass();    //work. However I think there must
newMain.messageReceived(buffer);        //be a better solution.
```

An array of arrays is the actual solution I plan on using to handle message concurrence.
For now this will do :)
If anyone had a better answer I'd be glad to read it.